# How to write a Bi-directional Value Converters to input a date with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Following code doesnt work because fromView() is called for each updates, resulting in wrong date construction. What the best solution to use bi-directional filters on dates with aurelia ?

```
<input type=text" value.bind="date | dateFormat: 'DD/MM/YY'"></input>

import moment from 'moment';
export class DateFormatValueConverter {
   toView(value, format) {
      return moment(value).format(format);
   }
   fromView(str, format){
     return moment(str, format);
   }
}
```

Comment: That should be happening. I'll review further.

Comment: In a future release of Aurelia you'll be able to choose which events cause the binding to re-evaluate.  In your case you probably want "blur" instead of "change"/"input".

Comment: Hi Jeremy, is Jim B's answer still the right way to do it? Thanks, Ingo

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but in case anyone else is wondering, to change the binding to re-evaluate on blur use:

```
<pre>

 <input type=text" value.bind="date | dateFormat: 'DD/MM/YY' &
 updateTrigger:'blur'"></input>;

</pre>
```

Comment: You made my day, mate! :)